# Static IP Address of eth0 is not showing on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, static-ip-address

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B with Raspbian Buster. I connected it with Wifi and it is working without any issues. I would like to enable the interface eth0 in order to use my Raspbi with Profinet (an industrial protocol).
So, I modified the file /etc/dhcpcd.conf/:

[/etc/dhcpcd.conf/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBzsp.png).

But the output of "ifconfig" is:

[eth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n8jv.png)

And the output of "route -v" is:
[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZJYR.png)

I would like to have the ip address of the interface "eth0" static and appearing and also able to be pinged. I tried a lot of stuffs on other forums like [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os/37921#37921): modifying the file /etc/network/interfaces. But this didn't work. I also set the eth0 interface up with "sudo ifconfig eth0 [ipadress] netmask 255.255.255.0 up". Ma wifi crashed after this... Can someone please help me? I'm stuck with this since a couple of weeks already. Thanks a lot. If you have any questions I can provide some screenshots.

Cheers

Comment: Can't see the images. On Raspian Buster `/etc/network/interfaces` does not work as in other distros. Maybe [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=140252) can help.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to embed an image here. But if you click on those links, it should work. I'll try the method of this link

Comment: Also, the interface may not be named eth0.  In older versions, eth0 was the wired interface.  In newer versions, the wired interface can be named something other than eth0 (but it will likely start with an "e").  ALSO... Your wireless interface will not be named "eth0".  It will be a name starting with a "w".

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` is used since Raspbian Stretch instead of instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Using your editor of choice, edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, scroll down to the example configuration, like below from mi Pi3B+, uncomment the lines and configure the parameters as per your needs.

```
# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1
```

Comment: I already did this (as I mentionned in my post with pictures). But it doesn't work. "eth0" stills shows no ip address and receives no packets. It doesn't send packets neither.  Can you please provide any tipps for me? I am really stuck with this since weeks :(

Answer (score 0):

update /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
```

restart dhcp service

```
 sudo service dhcpcd restart
```

and do not forget to inform a dhcp lease to your router if you want that this one does not allocate this ip to another material, that will avoid instability

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I already modified the file /etc/dhcpcd.conf (as you can see on the images I posted) then I restarted the dhcp service. But it didn't work for me. "ifconfig" stills shows ip address for eth0

Comment: can you look at the error log (syslog) after a restart of the service ? dhcpcd fail to run ?

Comment: I tested again and it works in mi RPi, but instead of doing a `sudo service dhcpcd restart` I make a `sudo reboot`.

Comment: @JeromeFavrou: Here are some errors when I run "cat /var/log/messages":
* device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
* Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files.
Dhcpcd was restarted without any issue. And my wifi is working again

Comment: @V.Lorz: I rebooted my RPi after restarting the dhcp service. But still the same issue

Comment: Try to revert your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to its original content. Sometimes, when there is a GUI tool that accomplishes a task that I need and is getting me crazy, I try to read the documentation of that tool or to observe how it modifies the files involved in the process. There is a GUI tool for configuring the network interfaces. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Also calling `ethtool eth0` gives as output:

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: Unknown!
Duplex: Unknown! (255)
Port: MII
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
               drv probe link
Link detected: no
```

Here some more details about my problem. I will be very grateful for help

Comment: You can edit your questions and add any details you consider useful for improving them.

Comment: The "operation not permitted" is a hint that you might be lacking permissions to properly run the command.  Try running it as root.